# What is the distribution function of a random variable X which has a constant fixed value of 2?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, finance

I remember reading somewhere that it is not possible for a continuous variable to take on an exact value so would the answer be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construe such a variable as either continuous or discrete. The probability density would not be a function but a measure, the Dirac Delta $\delta(x-2)$. Alternatively, the probability mass function is a Kronecker Delta, $\delta_{x2}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution)

Comment: To get the distribution how exactly would you integrate the Dirac Delta?

Comment: @chloeloughan The cdf  is $\int_{-\infty}^x\delta (y-2)dy=\Theta (x-2)$, a Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 2):

Find the CDF $F$ of $X$:

$$F(x) = \text{Pr}(X \le x)$$

- If $x < 2$, then $F(x) = \text{Pr}(\varnothing) = 0$.
- If $x \ge 2$, then $F(x) = 1$.

The PDF $f$ of $X$ is $$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$$

wherever defined.

Which is $0$ everywhere obviously.